# Regex match two value from string php

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

Hi i am trying to match two value by regex two conditions, But not able to do.

string is

```
MorText "gets(183,);inc();" for="text">Sweet" Mo
```

output trying is array

```
[
  183,
  "Sweet"
]
```

php regex code is

```
 preg_match_all('/gets\((.*?)\,|\>(.*?)\"/', $string, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your wanted output you can use:

```
/gets\((\d+),.*?>(.*?)\"/
```

PHP-Example:

```
$string = 'MorText "gets(183,);inc();" for="text">Sweet" Mo';

preg_match_all('/gets\((\d+),.*?>(.*?)\"/', $string, $matches);
    
print_r(array_merge($matches[1],$matches[2]));
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 183
    [1] => Sweet
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to match two values from the string **"gets(183,);inc();" for="text">Sweet"** using regular expressions. Here's an example regex that should work:

```
gets\((\d+),\);inc\(\);.*for="([^"]+)"
```

This regex has two capture groups:

1. **(\d+)** captures one or more digits inside the **gets()** function.
2. **"([^"]+)"** captures one or more characters inside the **for** attribute, excluding the double quotes.

Here's an example PHP code to use this regex and extract the values:

```
$string = 'gets(183,);inc(); for="text">Sweet';
$pattern = '/gets\((\d+),\);inc\(\);.*for="([^"]+)"/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) {
    $number = $matches[1]; // Captured value inside gets() function
    $text = $matches[2]; // Captured value inside the for attribute
    echo "Number: $number\n";
    echo "Text: $text\n";
} else {
    echo "No match found.\n";
}
```

This code will output:

```
Number: 183
Text: text
```